# why do we need container component in react-redux

Tags: reactjs, redux

I understand why we want to extract data logic from component into somewhere else, but why do we have to put this logic in a container component, rather than a controller-like javascript object which is connected to the component. This object will subscribe to the store and force the view to update itself when data changes. This way it does not has to be part of view structure and only handle data.

Thanks for help.

Comment: How will the controller-like object force the view to update? Container components make data reactivity easy by subscribing at the top level and passing down the data as props to it's children.

Comment: For connected components, you can call functions inside `mapStateToProps` and perform your data transformations in there, if you want.

Answer (score 0):

In Redux, `connect` replaces the need to use an explicit separate container component. So, essentially, you're completely right, you don't need to literally create another component that just renders the dumb component.

I create a dumb component and then I have a separate file where I `connect` the component, but there's no JSX or separate component in this file.

```
const DumbComponent = (props) => <div>{props.name}</div>;

const ContainerComponent = connect(mapStateToProps)(DumbComponent);
```